# Register user if not exist after loginAction FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

My problem is that I want to register a user if he does not exist after he entered his username. Authorization occurs without the use of a password, only by the login field. I use FOSUserBundle. What are the tips?

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules (_and could be closed_) You should go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the rules, read [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good question and get the best help.

Answer (score 0):

Override the FOS SecurityController overriding the path and creating your custom controller class.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseSecurityController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SecurityController extends BaseSecurityController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
      //change the parent logic

      //or verify the user and create before the login
      return parent::loginAction($request);
    }
}
```

**ADVISE, SECURITY WARNING**: your approach is not very secure, and in a public site can be *dangerous* without the use of at least a captcha to avoid robots, otherwise random users can be created using a loop.